# Google Now Choosing Weird Route

Tags: google-now, navigation

For at least a month or two, my Razr Maxx HD running the stock firmware Android 4.1.1 (9.1.41.XT926.Verizon.en.US) has done a great job at telling me how long it'll take to get home.

I know the route and don't need it to navigate me, obviously, but it has been picking the route that I actually follow. It gives me an estimated time for getting home, so that I can plan my evening around whether there's a severe problem on my route (traffic, road closure, construction, accident, etc.) and either route around it, or let others know that I'll be late, or if it's really terrible, stop somewhere for dinner before hitting the highway.

Suddenly, without changing my route or my driving habits at all, Google Now is telling me that it will take about three times longer to get home, and through an *extremely* indirect / inefficient route. So the time to home is very inaccurate because it isn't basing it on the correct route. Moreover, when I check other sources of traffic information online, I have no evidence that there is any sort of significant delay on my primary route -- at least, nothing significant enough that would make the alternate route faster, or even close to the same time (my primary route is one that takes about 25 minutes at full speed, 35 minutes in typical traffic, 60 minutes with a moderate to severe accident; the alternate route is saying 85 minutes!)

I double checked the settings for the Google Now traffic card, and the home and work addresses are set correctly. Google Navigation app picks the fastest route (the route I actually drive) when I ask it to take me home. So, why is Google Now telling me it'll take me an extremely long time to get home via an alternate route? Is there any way for me to set the route manually?

Comment: Yup. This is my life, every day: "54 mins to Home. 35 mins via alternate route." Why?!